# Site works remotely, but not locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I've done a lot of searching for various other similar questions, but none of those have had an answer for my issue:

I have a django site that uses a jquery draggable object which can be inserted into a sorted list.

On the server, this works perfectly.  However, I am trying to run using django's `runserver` and it does not work correctly.  The draggable object does drag, but it will not insert.

I can add more details about this code but since it works on the remote server, it seems that this code is working fine and the issue has something to do with my local configuration.

1. I've confirmed that the code is identical on the server and locally (using git)
2. I confirmed that the jquery script is being correctly loaded / is accessible (and has all permissions)
3. I've confirmed that there are no errors in the javascript console.
4. There are no cross-site requests
5. There are no absolute paths
6. I tried using both http://localhost:8000 and http://127.0.0.1:8000 (one answer I found said this might be important)
7. All of the django parts seem to be working (static files are loading, urls are properly populated from template tags, etc).
8. The same browser was used in all cases, and I tried both chrome and firefox.

What else am I missing that would cause the same site to not work locally that does work remotely?

Here are my css calls:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'evoat/assets/includes/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'evoat/css/draggable-style.css' %}">
<link href="{% static 'evoat/css/bootstrap-editable.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'evoat/css/oat.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">  <--my file
```

Here are my javascript calls:

```
<script src="{% static 'evoat/assets/includes/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'evoat/assets/includes/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'evoat/assets/includes/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'evoat/js/bootstrap-editable.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'evoat/js/oat.js' %}"></script>  <---my file
```

Comment: Ugh.  Sorry all -- this issue has a really dumb solution.  On the server, I have some data already in the database, but locally, it was empty.  I just have a bug where you can't drag into the empty sortable object...

Comment: @EMon You can post this as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @arogachev - Since it is unlikely to be useful to future readers, it would be better not answered since this will allow it to be [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/298072) (See reason #9 currently).